# Exception thrown by OleDbConnection.Open() while connecting to mdb file that has foreign characters in its name

Tags: c#, .net, oledbconnection

I need to read through an mdb file what may or maynot have a name in any foreign language. `OleDbConnection.Open()` method is throwing exception of 'not a valid file name' when **.mdb** file name has foreign language characters (I am testing it with russian). It works fine for 'Project.mdb' file but not for **'проект.mdb'**:

Just to be clear, the content of file is not an issue here, it is the issue with file's name.What could be the work around here so that same code works for all the languages?

```
var myDataTable = new DataTable();
string path = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\\test\\проект.mdb";
using (var conection = new OleDbConnection(path.ToString()))
{
int counter = 1;
conection.Open();
var query = "Select name From table1";
var command = new OleDbCommand(query, conection);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read() && counter < 2)
{
Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
counter++;
}
}
```

Comment: I think that you need to change CharacterSet of it from extended properties. You should find suitable characterset for Russian.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried editing the path string a little bit like: 
string path = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=\"D:\\test\\проект.mdb\";Extended Properties=\"Text;CharacterSet=UTF8;\""; but it does not seem to work either.

Comment: Using Extended Properties in this case, causes an exception like 'D\:test\проект.mdb' is not a valid path. And this exception occurs with the english file name as well, the connection string works fine when properties are not mentioned. Maybe there is some other way to pass these properties parameters in this case?